# Show/Hide AdvancedMarkerElement in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

How can `AdvancedMarkerElement`s be hidden/shown in Google Maps, specifically when using the `MarkerClusterer`?
With normal markers there is a [setVisible](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/marker#Marker.setVisible) method, but it doesn't appear that such a method exists for [AdvancedMarkers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/advanced-markers)?

Answer (score 0):

You can see the example at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/advanced-markers-zoom where they clear (*set to `null`*) the `.map` property of the advanced marker, in effect removing it from the map.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up just using the MarkerClusterer .clearMarkers and .addMarker methods.